# Postgres Error: Division by zero on bulk update SQL

Tags: postgresql, bulkinsert

I am getting this error: ERROR: division by zero. SQL state: 22012

Below is my query -

```
UPDATE USR
SET    PRCNT_SATSFCTN = (SELECT (SELECT COUNT(*) 
             FROM   ORDR 
             WHERE  USR.USR_ID = ORDR.USR_ID AND 
                    STSFD_SW = 'Y') * 100 / COUNT(*) 
                 FROM   ORDR
                     WHERE  USR.USR_ID = ORDR.USR_ID)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try:

```
UPDATE usr
SET    prcnt_satsfctn = o.share
FROM  (
    SELECT usr_id
         ,(count(CASE WHEN stsfd_sw = 'Y' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) * 100)
         / count(*) AS share   -- cannot be NULL!
    FROM   ordr
    GROUP  BY 1
    ) o
WHERE  usr.usr_id = o.usr_id
```

This query should be an improvment in several ways:

- Does **not** update any row in `usr`, where there is no matching row in `ordr`. That's where the division by 0 happens. (@Jan's query would update with `NULL` instead.)
- Division by 0 cannot happen here.
- Faster because it only needs to scan the table `ordr` once.
- Shorter, cleaner.

Answer (score 1):

As the error states. The calculation will fail if your ORDR Count(*) is zero. Maybe add an additional check ensure that the right side of your divide will never be zero.

```
UPDATE USR SET    PRCNT_SATSFCTN = (SELECT (SELECT COUNT(*) 
              FROM   ORDR 
              WHERE  USR.USR_ID = ORDR.USR_ID AND 
                     STSFD_SW = 'Y') * 100 / COUNT(*) 
                  FROM   ORDR
                      WHERE  USR.USR_ID = ORDR.USR_ID 
                      HAVING COUNT(*) > 0)
```

Comment: Thanks. But the PRCNT_SATSFCTN has a NOT NULL constraint on it. Is there a way I can set a default value when COUNT(*) = 0 ?

Comment: you can do something like:

    COALESCE( <blabla> / NULLIF( COUNT(*), 0 ), <DEFAULT_VALUE> )